# Averaging the quiz grade in the Array

Tags: c#, arrays

Once again I got an array that I cannot finish! I got it to populate and the information I input but I want it to also give me an average from the entire quizgrade. Basically every time I add a quiz grade to the array I want it to add them all together and then give me the average. I am out of good thoughts and cannot figure this part out. Can anybody help please. All help is appreciated! Thanks

Give a little history:
This code takes a persons name their number and their grade, adds it all to an array and then displays it in a list box. However, I need it to average the grades I place into the array as well but nothing I have tried works. Below is the code, maybe someone might be able to help.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int[] quizGrade = new int[1];
    string[] studentName = new string[1];
    string[] studentNumber = new string[1];
    int numberOfEntries = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addToArray();
        txtStudentName.Clear();
        txtStudentNumber.Clear();
        txtQuizGrade.Clear();
        addArrayElementsToListbox();
    }
    public void addArrayElementsToListbox()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Student Name \t Student Number \t Quiz Grade");
        for (int i = 0; i < studentName.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(studentName[i] + "\t" + studentNumber[i] + "\t\t" + quizGrade[i]);
        }
    }
    public void addToArray()
    {
        if (numberOfEntries == 0)
        {
            quizGrade[0] = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuizGrade.Text);
            studentName[0] = txtStudentName.Text;
            studentNumber[0] = txtStudentNumber.Text;
            numberOfEntries += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfEntries += 1;
            Array.Resize(ref quizGrade, numberOfEntries);
            Array.Resize(ref studentName, numberOfEntries);
            Array.Resize(ref studentNumber, numberOfEntries);
            quizGrade[numberOfEntries - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuizGrade.Text);
            studentName[numberOfEntries - 1] = txtStudentName.Text;
            studentNumber[numberOfEntries - 1] = txtStudentNumber.Text;
        }
    }
    public void txtAverage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            txtStudentName.Clear();
            txtStudentNumber.Clear();
            txtQuizGrade.Clear();
            Array.Clear(studentName, 0,studentName.Length);
            Array.Clear(studentNumber, 0,studentNumber.Length);
            Array.Clear(quizGrade, 0,quizGrade.Length);
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have to use arrays?

Comment: Why not do something like `int avg = quizGrade.Sum() / quizGrade.Length;`? This would add them all together, and then divide by the number of grades. *Disclaimer* I've been up all night and haven't had coffee yet.

Comment: LINQ provides you with `.Average()` which works on `IEnumerable<int>`, which your array is.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks I tried your code and did not get any errors but it does not post to my text box. avg = Convert.ToInt32(txtAverage.Text);

Comment: If you want to add it to the textbox, after you do the avg, you have to assign it to the textbox, so something like `txtAverage.Text = avg.ToString()`.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks I tried this as well and I still cannot get it to go into the box. I am totally confused why it will not show something in the box.

Comment: You can add entries with a `List<Student>` and convert  it into an array with `.ToArray()` only when needed.

Comment: @PaulSkinner. Try making it a label instead. Since it's an average that you're calculating, you don't want it to be a textbox.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks I got it to work with what you originally said, I just needed to place it inside the public void addToArray else field and it worked. This was driving me crazy. Why did you not post  like the others? I could have liked your answer which gives you more points? Your solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a Foreach loop and add it all together then divide the number of entries. like below.

```
int total = 0;

foreach(int a in quizGrade)
{
    total = total + a;
}
```

then divide by the total count of the array.

```
total = total / numberOfEntries;
```

Something like that. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the [Enumerable.Average(TSource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548874.aspx) functions.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get rid of most of the complexity by bundling the grade records together.

```
public class StudentQuizGrade {
    public string StudentName {get; set;}
    public string StudentNumber {get; set;}
    public int QuizGrade {get; set;}
}
```

We are removing the "don't repeat yourself" error in repeating the size of the arrays. This lets us write what you already have as

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    StudentQuizGrade [] quizGrades = new StudentQuizGrade [0];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addToArray();
        txtStudentName.Clear();
        txtStudentNumber.Clear();
        txtQuizGrade.Clear();
        addArrayElementsToListbox();
    }
    public void addArrayElementsToListbox()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Student Name \t Student Number \t Quiz Grade");
        foreach (StudentQuizGrade quizGrade in quizGrades)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(quizGrade.StudentName + "\t" + quizGrade.StudentNumber + "\t\t" + quizGrade.QuizGrade);
        }
    }
    public void addToArray()
    {
        Array.Resize(ref quizGrades, quizGrades.Count + 1);
        quizGrade[quizGrades.Count- 1] = new StudentQuizGrade() {
            QuizGrade = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuizGrade.Text);
            StudentName = txtStudentName.Text;
            StudentNumber = txtStudentNumber.Text;
        }
    }

    public void txtAverage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            txtStudentName.Clear();
            txtStudentNumber.Clear();
            txtQuizGrade.Clear();
            Array.Clear(quizGrades, 0,quizGrades.Length);
        }

}
```

Next, we'll clean up the repetition of what happens when the array is changed. We'll do this by adding an event to raise whenever we change what is in the array. Things that need to be notified of it can be added to `QuizGradesChanged`, and things that change `quizGrades` should call `QuizGradesChanged()`. We'll also refactor clearing the add inputs with a new method, `clearAddInputs()`, and drop some unnecessary methods.

```
public delegate void EventHandler();

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler QuizGradesChanged;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        QuizGradesChanged += addArrayElementsToListbox;
    }
    StudentQuizGrade [] quizGrades = new StudentQuizGrade [0];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addToArray();
        clearAddInputs();
    }

    private void clearAddInputs()
    {
        txtStudentName.Clear();
        txtStudentNumber.Clear();
        txtQuizGrade.Clear();
    }

    public void addArrayElementsToListbox()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Student Name \t Student Number \t Quiz Grade");
        foreach (StudentQuizGrade quizGrade in quizGrades)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(quizGrade.StudentName + "\t" + quizGrade.StudentNumber + "\t\t" + quizGrade.QuizGrade);
        }
    }

    public void addToArray()
    {
        Array.Resize(ref quizGrades, quizGrades.Count + 1);
        quizGrade[quizGrades.Count- 1] = new StudentQuizGrade() {
            QuizGrade = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuizGrade.Text);
            StudentName = txtStudentName.Text;
            StudentNumber = txtStudentNumber.Text;
        }
        QuizGradesChanged();
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearAddInputs();
        Array.Clear(quizGrades, 0,quizGrades.Length);
        QuizGradesChanged();
    }    
}
```

Finally we can add an average of the quiz grades. We'll have a method, `recalculateAverage()` that recalculates the average and displays it in your `txtAverage` control.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        QuizGradesChanged += addArrayElementsToListbox;
        QuizGradesChanged += recalculateAverage
    }

    public void recalculateAverage() {
        if (quizGrades.Count > 0) {
           txtAverage.Text = quizGrades.Select(x => (decimal) x.QuizGrade).Average().ToString();
        } else {
           txtAverage.Text = "No grades to average";
        }
    }
```

**Edit: arrays ... ugh**

There's probably a bug in

```
private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clearAddInputs();
    Array.Clear(quizGrades, 0,quizGrades.Length);
    QuizGradesChanged();
}
```

I'd be more confident that this works correctly:

```
private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clearAddInputs();
    quizGrades = new StudentQuizGrade[0];
    QuizGradesChanged();
}
```

Comment: I know it has been a very long time since I posted to this and you all helped answer the questions but I still want to say thank you to everyone!